# Regex strings for uploads folder

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm using "Safe Search and Replace on Database with Serialized Data v3.1.0" to do a search and replace of my database. I've been trying to write it myself but haven't had any luck and Google seems to not have the answer I'm looking for.

Basically I need a string that will target upload folders from 2010-2015 with jpg|jpeg|png|gif file types that I can replace the string with a simple placeholder.png file I created.

Here's what I've managed to make that doesn't seem to work lol sorry if it's just terrible:

```
(uploads)(.*?).(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)
```

or

```
^\/wp-content\/uploads\/((2014|2013|2012|2011)|(2015\/(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08)))\/(.+)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)
```

I've tried other variations I've made but when conducting a "dry run" it states that 0 cells would have been changed.

The image urls are full and not relative.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Is there a directory structure like `uploads/new.jpg` or something like that ?

Comment: It's date based so like http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image.jpg would be an example.

Comment: Do you only want up to August 2015 or what? Because that's what your regex implies. Also you left out 2010...

Comment: Sorry yeah I only need to back like... I don't want to change images from the last 6 months. And 2010 yes sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
(uploads\/201[0-5]\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/.*?\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg))
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/dG5jC4/2)

Comment: This seems to have worked but it states. I have over 12,000 posts and it states 1699 cells would have been changed. I'll see if I can check but I can't believe I only have 1699 images inserted into 12,000+ posts. Any idea what may be up? maybe it is only 1699 ? lol

Comment: There may be some image links not covered by this pattern. But that needs to find out. If that's the case, the above pattern needs to be improved. Maybe there are image links in multi lines? Then please try: `(uploads\/201[0-5]\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[\s\S]*?\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg))`.

Comment: Your latest code, same amount. Maybe I really do only have 1699 lol

Comment: When I remove post_content as the only column to search it comes up with 60,000 cells to change... so maybe that's what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's no easy job to get the true value of total. You cannot count it one by one;)

Comment: I know and I appreciate your help. I'm testing this out now on my staging site and will let you know momentarily.

Comment: This did it! And once minor change to the code and I was able to strip featured images as well!!! Thank you! Not sure how to vote best answer, I think I hit the check mark to the left? lol

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you:

```
^\/wp-content\/uploads\/(201[0-4]\/\d{2}|2015\/0[0-8])\/(.+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg))$
```

I tested it here: [regexp101](https://regex101.com/r/nI0rD4/4).
You will find more in depth-explanation there.

Be aware that the uploads folder format can be changed in the Dashboard.

Comment: He said he needs 2010-2015 only.

Comment: says 0 cells would have been changed on my dry run. :(

Comment: can you post a sample of your dataset on regexp101 ?

Comment: I may be a bit noob for that... dataset? like the database?

Comment: I meant just some sample content, like i posted in the regexp101 link with the placekitten url. But i changed my content, so i have a link in 2009 and one in september 2015. Just click the link in my answer above and check if my sample content matches yours.